# Is there any way to skip the newline character in input()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, function

> The problem with this is that, when a paragraph is pasted to get the result the function(program) could not handle the sentences after the line breaks because it only get executed on the first line not on another after that.

```
def lenth(paragraph):
    splited = paragraph.split(" ")
    txt = len(splited)
    if txt == 1:
        print(txt, "word")
    else:
        print(txt, "words")
lenth(input("Enter the paragraph: "))
```

> Try this paragraph excluding ---Start--- or ---End---

```
---Start---
This is for testing purposes only and 
for the 
checking 
of the function
---End---
```

Comment: `input()` always get only one line. if you need more then you have to use loop which uses `input()` many times.

Comment: can't understand please specify the code

Comment: `while True: lines += input()` but it would need method to recognize end of data. It can be empty line.

Comment: please answer, still confused

Comment: Why do you want to *exclude* the ``Start`` and ``End`` markers from your input? You need *some* way for your program to know which lines belong to a paragraph and such markers are ideal for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input()` was created to read only one line. To read more you would have to use `input()` in loop but you would have to somehow inform loop when text is over - for example you can put empty line after paragraph

```
lines = []

while True:
    line = input()
    if not line: # exit loop when empty line.
        break
    lines.append(line)

text = '\n'.join(lines)

print('>', text, '<')
```

---

Problem can be if you have paragraph with empty line between other lines. In Linux and maybe in Windows in some programs you can use `Ctrl+D` to inform program that it is end of file and then it send EOF error (End Of File)

```
lines = []

while True:
    try:
        line = input()  # press `Ctrl+D` to end of data
        lines.append(line)
    except EOFError:
        break

text = '\n'.join(lines)

print('>', text, '<')
```

Using `sys.stdin.read()` you can write it shorter

```
import sys

try:
    text = sys.stdin.read()  # press `Ctrl+D` to end of data
except EOFError:
    pass

print('>', text, '<')
```

Or maybe even without `try/except`

```
import sys

text = sys.stdin.read()  # press `Ctrl+D` to end of data

print('>', text, '<')
```

It should works also with text redirected from file

```
python script.py < file_with_paragrph.txt
```